# Mongoose mixed SchemaType

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I couldn't understand that for what purpose mongoose schemaType is used for. If someone could explain it will be helpful.

I'm have to reference another schema from a schema i want to know if we can get the details of all schema together when we do a findOne() on mongoose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mixed schema means whatever you want the type to be. if you input a String, Number, Date, mongoose will let you do that. However according to [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html), mongoose ref does not work with mixed.

```
Note: ObjectId, Number, String, and Buffer are valid for use as refs.
```

if you use mixed, and ref it, you won't be able to query it back.

If you start all over(delete the database and reinsert again), use ObjectId instead of Mixed.

```
var storySchema = Schema({
  author : { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Person' },
});
```

If you wish to retain old database, the best way is to change mixed to string

```
  var storySchema = Schema({
      author : { type: String, ref: 'Person' },
    });
```

Comment: Thank you i got it.